# JMETER How to pass multiple users in a test plan with two APIs i

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a scenario where I have to hit an api, extract a value from it and pass it to another api.

This is how my test plan is setup.
Testplan
—

```
>Thread Group
       —>HTTPS request 
          —>extracted variable 
       —>For each controller (input from prev response)
         —>HTTPS request




I have used a for each controller because I will have multiple ids in one response and I have to extract all the ids and then loop it.



My script is perfectly working fine for one user but for multiple users it is failing. Please help.
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot "help" you without knowing how exactly it's "failing".

The only recommendation I can provide so far is to [temporarily enable storing JMeter request and response data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter) by either manipulating [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) or using a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer). Also take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) and look for any suspicious entries

This way you will be able to tell for sure why the request fails, for example the system was overloaded and didn't properly respond to 1st HTTPS request hence data extraction failed hence 2nd request wasn't executed.

Comment: Hi, failing because of assertion since the values in one api doesn’t match with other api. The values are not matching because of multiple user only. 
When I check through postman I don’t see any discrepancy through postman between those apis.